# How to avoid decimal bugs in javascript?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, math, quasar

I am making a form for adding a product using VueJS and Quasar framework.

I am having issues with the calculations in a small but critical way.
Sometimes I the product gets the price comes out wrong with like .01 I googled my way to find out there is Something with the way Javascript calculates decimal values, apparently not an issue with Integer values.

I quickly made a jsfiddle where you can recreate my issue by adding 100 in the first field ( price ) and then changing the VAT select to what ever ( the fiddle has a bug and calculates with the previously selected value and not the current ).

It is supposed to stay at 100 but it returns 100.01.

https://jsfiddle.net/5y60s2rk/18/

**Here comes the code from the real project**

```
   <q-input
    v-model="product.price"
    type="number"
    @input="updatePriceIncVat"
  />

  <q-input
    v-model="product.price_vat"
    type="number"
    @input="updatePriceExclVat"
  />

  <q-select
    v-model="product.vat"
    :options="selectVat"
    emit-value
    map-options
    @input="updatePriceExclVat"
  />

  data () {
    return {
      product: {
        price: '',
        price_vat: '',
        vat: 1.24
      },
      selectVat: [
        {
          label: '0%',
          value: 1
        },
        {
          label: '10%',
          value: 1.10
        },
        {
          label: '14%',
          value: 1.14
        },
        {
          label: '24%',
          value: 1.24
        }
      ]
  }
  methods: {
    updatePriceIncVat () {
      this.product.price_vat = Number((this.product.price / this.product.vat).toFixed(2))
    },
    updatePriceExclVat () {
      this.product.price = Number((this.product.price_vat * this.product.vat).toFixed(2))
    }
  }
}
```

**I have tried**
round() , trying to avoid decimals by multiplying with 100 , removing the decimals and dividing again to the correct number. But at somepoint I still end up with multiplying a decimal and It messes it up.

Thank you if you came this far, I really appreciate you using your time to help me out.

Comment: input, 100.00 => 80.65, input 100.01 result remain the same 80.65, checked a couple  of the others vat calculators, they behave they same, don't worry )

Comment: this is cumulative roundoff error.

Comment: Would it make sense if you put on your ```<q-select>``` ```@change``` instead of ```@input```?

Comment: qiAlex, I also found vat calculators with the same issue. But for me it’s not just a calculator, it sets the price of product. And sometimes a product that cost 25,00€ shows up as 25,01€. 

This is a small difference but critical since the app generates invoices and you cant be sending faulty invoices, even by 1c

Comment: Anatoly, great thx, do you know how to go around it?

Comment: Nikola, thx for your answer, but that would not make a difference in the problem i am having.

Comment: You should decide what kind of a price would be the source and then another one will always be calculated.

Comment: Its a simple math issue: Round (use `toFixed()` here) only if displaying the result. So remove `toFixed()` in the calculation part.